# how to catch a tag by "class" attribute in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to catch a tag from the html code  below.

```
<pre class="sourceHeading">          Line data    Source code</pre>
<pre class="source">
```

now I catch "pre" tag by `pres = soup.find_all("pre")`.
then I want to catch the tag whose class's name is source.
but when I type like :

```
pre = soup.find(class = "source")
```

the "class" attribute will clash with python keyword "class".
how can I catch the tag whose `class = "source"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the word `class` is a keyword, that it cannot be used as an argument name. For that reason, you've to add a trailing underscore:

```
pre = soup.find(class_='source')
```

Or, pass a dictionary to the `attrs` parameter:

```
pre = soup.find(attrs={'class' : 'source'})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
pre = soup.find_all("pre", {'class':'source'})
```

OR

```
pre = soup.find("pre", {'class':'source'})
```

**Note:** In your example your code crashes beacause `class` is a keyword, it cannot be used as an argument name.

Hope this will help you! Thankyou! :)